# Simulated Annealing in R: GenSA running time

Tags: r, optimization, simulated-annealing

I am using simulated annealing, as implemented in R's package `GenSa` (function `GenSA`), to search for values of input variables that result in "good values" (compared to some baseline) of a highly dimensional function. I noticed that setting maximum number of calls of the objective function has no effect on the running time. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Here is a modification of the example given in `GenSA` help file.

```
library(GenSA)

Rastrigin <- local({ 
  index <- 0  
  function(x){    
    index <<- index + 1    
    if(index%%1000 == 0){
      cat(index, "   ")
    }    
    sum(x^2 - 10*cos(2*pi*x)) + 10*length(x)    
  }  
})

set.seed(1234)
dimension <- 1000
lower <- rep(-5.12, dimension)
upper <- rep(5.12, dimension)
out <- GenSA(lower = lower, upper = upper, fn = Rastrigin, control = list(max.call = 10^4))
```

Even though the `max.call` is specified to be 10,000, `GenSA` calls the objective function more than 46,000 times (note that the objective is called within a local environment in order to track the number of calls). The same problem rises when trying to specify the maximum running time via `max.time`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an answer by the package maintainer :

> max.call and max.time are soft limits that do not include local
>   searches that are performed before reaching these limits. The
>   algorithm does not stop the local search strategy loop before its end
>   and this may exceed the limitation that you have set but will stop
>   after that last search. We have designed the algorithm that way to
>   make sure that the algorithm isn't stopped in the middle of searching
>   valley. Such an option to stop anywhere will be implemented in the
>   next release of the package.